# How do I handle errors when bundling multiple ajax calls into jQuery.when()?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to wait on multiple AJAX calls without nesting callbacks one inside the other.

From [this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) documentation, I understand it's possible using `jQuery.when()`.

```
$.when($.ajax("/page1.php"), $.ajax("/page2.php")).done(function(a1,  a2){
    /* a1 and a2 are arguments resolved for the 
        page1 and page2 ajax requests, respectively */
   var jqXHR = a1[2]; /* arguments are [ "success", statusText, jqXHR ] */
   if ( /Whip It/.test(jqXHR.responseText) ) {
      alert("First page has 'Whip It' somewhere.");
   }
});
```

However, from the supplied example, I don't understand how errors are handled. In a normal `jquery.ajax` call, I supply an `error` callback in the options.

Ideally, what I'd like is for a supplied error callback to be called when at least one of the ajax calls causes an error.

Comment: You can get results in `a1[0]` and `a2[0]`. Then you can test for `"success"` or `"error"`.

Comment: Are you sure? I've tried it, and the function passed to `done` just isn't called.

Answer (score 0):

The correct thing is to chain `then` to `when`, instead of `done`.

For example:

```
$.when(
   $.ajax("/page1.php", {
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
      // handle the error for this specific call
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
      // handle the success for this specific call
    }
   }), 
   $.ajax("/page2.php"), {
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
      // handle the error for this specific call
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
      // handle the success for this specific call
    }
   }).then(
   function(){
     // all calls succeeded
   },
   function(){
     // at least one of the calls failed
   }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me using jquery-2.0.3